# How to set cookies in a variable and use it again: PUPPETEER

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i'm trying to insert ALL browser cookies in a variable and then use it again later.

My attempt:

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs').promises;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
    headless: false,
    executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
 const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
```

Below, it's my code to get cookies, and it work, but now it print a error message.

```
 const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
 const all_browser_cookies = (await client.send('Network.getAllCookies')).cookies;
 const current_url_cookies = await page.cookies();
 var third_party_cookies = all_browser_cookies.filter(cookie => cookie.domain !== current_url_cookies[0].domain);
```

and below it's the seccond page (that will use cookies)

```
 (async () => {
    const browser2 = await puppeteer.launch({
    });
    const url = 'https://www.google.com/';
    const page2 = await browser2.newPage();

  try{
  await page2.setCookie(...third_party_cookies);
  await page2.goto(url);
  }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
  }
  await browser2.close()
  })();

})();
```

until yesterday it works, but today it's appearing this message error:

```
Error: Protocol error (Network.setCookies): Invalid parameters Failed to deserialize params.cookies.expires - BINDINGS: double value expected at position 662891
```

Anyone know what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7029

You are saving an array of cookies and page.setCookie only works with one cookie. Yo have to iterate trought your array like that:

```
for (let i = 0; i < third_party_cookies.length; i++) {
    await page2.setCookie(third_party_cookies[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@julio-codesal's suggestion is ok, but according to the puppeteer documentaion it is ok to use page.setCookie with an array, as long as you destructure it, e.g.:

```js
await page.setCookie(...arr)
```

source: https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pagesetcookiecookies

Not exactly sure what it is, but the error the OP has is something else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).